# Why does "vertical-align: middle" push text below surrounding text?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Eg.

```html
1234<span style="vertical-align: middle">567</span>890
```

Will render with `567` slightly below the surrounding numbers.

http://jsfiddle.net/zBy9D/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by others, elements have a `vertical-align` of `baseline` by default.

In regards to why `middle` is lower than `baseline`, MDN says the following:

> **middle**
>
> Aligns the middle of the element with the middle of lowercase
> letters in the parent.

Since the height of the font text is greater than that of lowercase letters, the text becomes slightly lower.

Comment: And so the only way to fix my example would be to wrap the `1234` and `890` in their own `<span>` tags with `vertical-align: middle`? (The `567` actually has other styles, so it still needs to be in its own span.)

Comment: There's no "fix" for your example, since it is working as intended. It sounds like there is some other issue you're trying to solve though. If you're having trouble with that, it may be best to put it in a new SO question since it is a separate issue. That being said, using the same `vertical-align` value should indeed align them vertically.

Comment: Note that this only applies for fonts where the descender is sufficiently small. Imagine a font where the descender took more that half the height of the font. The midpoint of the lower case letter would be even higher, and the midpoint of the element would necessarily be lower. So the text of the element would have to be shifted higher to make the midpoints line up.

Comment: @Alohci I'm not familiar with how descenders and ascenders are treated in the calculation of height, but it makes more sense to me for descenders to either lower or not change the middle of lowercase letters, since the "top" of lowercase letters is below that of uppercase letters. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What you missing is that the middle of the element is half the total height of the font, whereas the middle of the lowercase letters in the parent is half the height of the lowercase letters (formally half the `x-height`) **sitting on the parent's baseline**. So if the baseline is high enough, the second value will exceed the first, otherwise the second value will be less than the first. So the characters may be shifted up or down, depending on the font.

Answer (score 2):

It's because text has, by default, `vertical-align: baseline`. Middle's slightly lower than baseline.

Comment: baseline is the line that sits under the bottom of letters like n, a, b, and not q.