# vertical-align with middle of capital letters instead of lowercase letters?

Tags: html, css

I have read [various](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/) [articles](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) about `vertical-align`. I have also seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21115195/1959975) too, but [both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115333/1959975) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115253/1959975) say it is because of the surrounding text defaulting to `vertical-align: baseline;`. However, this is not the case below:

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* font-size: 1em; and line-height: 1em; do not change anything */
}
```

```html
<span>0<span>0<span>0<span>0<span>0<span>0<span>0<span>0<span>0<span>0</span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

Everything is set to `vertical-align: middle;`, yet there is still a downward skew of the text. Interestingly, [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115333/1959975) quotes MDN, which states that `vertical-align: middle;` aligns with the middle of the *lowercase* letters in the parent element. This explains the weird skewing, but even with all lowercase letters, the skewing [still happens](https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/uncw8fjq/). Using `display: inline-block;` [doesn't work either](https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/t4mm9v76/).

I'll set aside my opinion about how counter-intuitive this is, and instead ask: is there a way to `vertical-align` with the middle of the *capital* letters instead? Or, better yet, the middle of the *entire line*? I'm looking to preserve the structure of the HTML while also allowing e.g. [images and other tall things](https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/vLor7nro/) in the lines - not just text.

In short: the skew is what I *don't* want, but I still want inline elements to be vertically aligned to the middle of their lines, regardless of the HTML structure.

EDIT: [with `vertical-align`](https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/sm1f4atq/) and [without `vertical-align`](https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/sm1f4atq/5/) (make the viewer as wide as possible)

Comment: The skew you're seeing in the jsFiddle is expected behavior because the `span` tags are nested. The style cascades from one level of nesting to the next, aligning the top of each child with the middle of its parent. If you simply remove the vertical-align, the text stays straight. It's not quite clear what you're trying to align from the example; can you provide a more specific problem you are trying to solve with vertical-align?

Comment: @dartonw `vertical-align: middle;` does not align the top of the child with the middle of the parent - it aligns the middle of the child with the middle of the lowercase letters in the parent. If what you said were true the skew would be much more exaggerated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason the elements must be nested? Simply putting the spans side-by-side functions in the way you seem to want.

Comment: I misspoke. But either way, the outcome is expected behavior.

Comment: @DACrosby Consider what happens when you want to put multiple HTML tags around a single word, or do *anything* more complex than plain text.

Comment: Can you give an example of when multiple tags would be preferable over a single span with css classes around your word?

Comment: @DACrosby Maybe when you want to **have *emphasized* text** - how do you do that with a single tag? See also: https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/sm1f4atq/

Comment: So when you said "multiple tags on a single word", what you meant was "multiple tags throughout a phrase", which I fully understand.

Comment: It seems StackOverflow itself has given you your answer. Inspect Element on your last comment and see how they set up your double emphasised phrase - by not setting the vertical-align property at all. Verified [on your own jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm1f4atq/4/)

Comment: @DACrosby no, it still has the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/sm1f4atq/5/ make the html viewer as wide as you can

Comment: Remove all of the extra styling, let the browser handle it. https://jsfiddle.net/sm1f4atq/6/

Comment: It appears we've left the realm of your original question. You'd have better luck asking a new one inquiring on inline images not aligning properly when the text size varies - it's a good question and I can't say I know the answer to that one.

Comment: @DACrosby what should happen to this question? Is it a bad idea to delete it?

Comment: There's no reason to. You asked a legitimate question, the answer has been flushed out and new questions have come up. If you feel this question specifically has been answered, mark the answer below as correct (the little check mark next to it). Otherwise, wait and see if anyone else answers it more completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align` is intended to set the alignment of sibling elements (["elements set next to each other on a line"](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)) - not from parent to child.

In this example, I have several `span`s next to each other and they align correctly. When you start nesting them without sibling elements the alignment doesn't know what to align to (well, I don't know what it'd align to at leas, but nothing immediately intuitive). If you give the nested elements a sibling, they align correctly again.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<span>0</span>
<span>0</span>
<span>P</span>
<span>p</span>
<span>R</span>
<span>r</span>
<span>q</span>
<span>Q</span>
<span>0
   1<span>
     2<span>
       3<span>
         4<span>
           5
           <span>5.1</span>
           <span>5.2</span>
           <span>5.3</span>
           <span>5.4</span>
         </span>
       </span>
     </span>
   </span>
 </span>
```

**Update**

It seems you're looking to simply not set the vertical-align property at all. The method browsers use inherently functions as you're looking for

Comment: Even in your own example the problem is evident - look at how the spaces are a pixel higher than the letters. Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/sm1f4atq/

Comment: With regards to your update: this is what happens when `vertical-align` is not set: https://i.imgur.com/lOeRYvA.png

Comment: Thats due to the extra styling you have set. line-height, height, etc. Remove it all.

Comment: @LB-- see https://jsfiddle.net/dartonw/ntm87tmk/. If you want things to line up, just size them consistently. Also, see https://jsfiddle.net/dartonw/cw20w1q6/1/, where the red lines do overlap the black lines. No vertical-align anywhere.

Comment: @dartonw the point of the oversized image was that it is a real-world scenario.

Comment: @LB-- http://jsfiddle.net/dartonw/t55w8yv2/1/ may be more like what you're looking for. Part of the issue is that you're applying the same styles to too many elements.

Comment: @dartonw unfortunately no, but this is way off topic so I'll research it myself.